# How do I make a method that returns a string array in C++?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, c++-cli

I have a problem, I am trying to convert from C# to C++/CLI and I don't know how to return a string array in a method.
The problem is that strings are showing up as numbers instead of strings.

Here is the Method:

```
static array<String^> ^Split(String^ Victim, char SplitPoint)
{
int Index=0;
        for each(char Char in Victim)
            if(Char==SplitPoint)
                Index++;
        array<String^> ^SplitStrings = gcnew array<String^>;
        Index=0;
        for each(char Char in Victim)
        {
            if(Char==SplitPoint)
                Index++;
            else
                SplitStrings[Index]=SplitStrings[Index]+Char;
        }
        return SplitStrings;
    };
```

and the original method in C# looks like this:

```
    public static string[] Split(string Victim, char SplitPoint)
    {
        int Index = 0;
        foreach (char Char in Victim)
            if (Char == SplitPoint)
                Index++;
        string[] SplitStrings = new string[Index + 1];
        Index = 0;
        foreach (char Char in Victim)
        {
            if (Char == SplitPoint)
            {
                Index++;
            }
            else
                SplitStrings[Index] = SplitStrings[Index] + Char;
        }
        return SplitStrings;
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to return a managed array of managed strings, or are you trying to return a native array of native strings?

Comment: A little off-topic remark: using Char as a variable identifier makes your code really hard to read.

Comment: why are you not using `System::String::Split` for this?

Comment: Oh, ya.  I name variables really weird.  And I think the System::String::Split Doesn't really work for this, but this took like two minutes in C# so it didn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

It's really unclear what your actual question is, so here's a direct translation of your C# code to C++/CLI:

```cpp
public:
    static array<String^>^ Split(String^ Victim, wchar_t SplitPoint)
    {
        int Index = 0;
        for each (wchar_t Char in Victim)
            if (Char == SplitPoint)
                Index++;
        array<String^>^ SplitStrings = gcnew array<String^>(Index + 1);
        Index = 0;
        for each (wchar_t Char in Victim)
        {
            if (Char == SplitPoint)
                Index++;
            else
                SplitStrings[Index] = SplitStrings[Index] + Char;
        }
        return SplitStrings;
    }
```

In particular, note that `char` in C++/CLI equates to `System::SByte`, not `System::Char` -- the native name for the latter is `wchar_t`. (Also, you didn't specify the dimensions of `SplitStrings`.)